# How to create and alter properties of windows explorer?

Tags: powershell

I'll keep this question short. I am wondering if it is possible to create a windows explorer window?

I came across the 'Find' explorer window ( Win + F ) or `search-ms:` and would like to know if there are any properties of these windows you can alter?

Comment: It's a bit unclear what you're asking here. You can open a new explorer window with `Start-Process` if you like: `Start-Process explorer 'search-ms:'`

Comment: can I edit properties of this explorer window such as screen size maybe alter how the search results appear etc